# Cannot add HtmlAgilityPack as a reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This shouldn't be difficult, but I can't add HtmlAgilityPack.dll as a reference in an empty C# project. Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded HtmlAgilityPack.1.4.5.zip.
2. Unzipped it.
3. In the Solution Explorer, I right-clicked on References and selected 'Add Reference...'.
4. I use Visual Studio 2008 and selected Net20/HtmlAgilityPack.dll.

There is now a yellow triangle on the HtmlAgilityPack.dll and I can't edit the path in its properties. If I remove it and add it again, the same thing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error message does it state when you hover over the reference?

Comment: What version of .NET is _your_ application using?

Comment: There is no error message when I hoover over the reference. I am using C# 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with 1.4.5, try to download the 1.4.0 version.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/44954

I'm not sure why it doesn't work, but if you look at [here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/364171) you will see others with the same problem.

Quoting ttraguth:

> Hi,
>
> I have the same problem here integrating the current 1.45 binaries in
>   an .NET 3.5 Application.
>
> dotPeek also shows the assembly as 4.0.
>
> Maybe your .targets broke?

Comment: Optionally, download the source code, add the project and reference that.

Comment: @Oded Yup ;). 
KasperHansen I'm glad I could help.